# Python: If-statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm currently doing a project in Python, where I have an if-statement (elif) on a server (socket), which takes commands from a client.

I'm having some issues with an if-statement, which is supposed to change the "boatIsAt" value if called for.

The code is:

```
#Initial state of the boat
boatIsAt = "left"

#Some code..

if data == "Q" and chickenIsAt == "left":
    data = "chicken"
    chickenIsAt = "boatLeft"

# Some other elif-statements..

elif data == "R" and boatIsAt == "left":
    data = "Row"
    boatIsAt = "right"

elif data == "R" and boatIsAt == "right":
    data = "Row"
    boatIsAt = "left"`
```

The problem is, that when I call the "R"/row the first time, it changes "boatIsAt" to "right", but when I try to call "R"/row again, and it should go from right to left, it goes to the right again.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well I don't know if this is the problem but that is not python syntax at all. Comments in python are single line only with the `#` starting the line. If needs to be lowercase and you may wanna clean up your whitespace for legibility

Comment: To add to @Tom's comment, I don't even see an `if` statement legally defined here.

Comment: In addition, in classic Python syntax after if statement there is a colon (:).

Comment: I changed the commenting format for StackOverflow, have the "#" single-line comments in WingIDE, of course. Updating my code right now to make it more "readable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always set

```
boatIsAt = "left"
```

unconditionally at the beginning, so your first `elif` is entered and `boatIsAt` is set to `"right"`.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

Figured out what I had done wrong.
I had put boatIsAt = "left" inside a while-loop:

```
while 1:
    boatIsAt = "left"
```

which made it go back to left every time I ran a command to the server. Placing it outside/above the while statement fixed it.